# Use of undeclared type or module `std` when used in a separate module

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I have the following code:

```
pub mod a {
    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        println!("{:?}", std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
    }
}
```

I get errors when I compile this:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `std`
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |         println!("{}", std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
  |                        ^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `std`
```

However, removing the inner module and compiling the code it contains by itself works fine:

```
#[test]
pub fn test() {
    println!("{:?}", std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
}
```

What am I missing here? I get the same errors if the module is in a separate file:

**main.rs**

```
pub mod a;
```

**a.rs**

```
#[test]
pub fn test() {
    println!("{:?}", std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

By default, the compiler inserts `extern crate std;` at the beginning of the crate root (the crate root is the file that you pass to `rustc`). This statement has the effect of adding the name `std` to the crate's root namespace and associating it with a module that contains the public contents of the `std` crate.

However, in child modules, `std` is not automatically added in the module's namespace. This is why the compiler cannot resolve `std` (or anything that starts with `std::`) in a module.

There are many ways to fix this. First, you can add `use std;` in a module to make the name `std` refer, within that module, to the root `std`. Note that in `use` statements, the path is treated as absolute (or "relative to the crate's root namespace"), whereas everywhere else, paths are treated as relative to the current namespace (be it a module, a function, etc.).

```
pub mod a {
    use std;

    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        println!("{:?}", std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
    }
}
```

You can also use a `use` statement to import more specific items. For example, you can write `use std::fs::remove_file;`. This lets you avoid having to type the whole path to `remove_file` and just use the name `remove_file` directly within that module:

```
pub mod a {
    use std::fs::remove_file;

    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        println!("{:?}", remove_file("Somefilehere")));
    }
}
```

Finally, you can avoid using `use` altogether by prefixing the path with `::` to ask the compiler to resolve the path from the crate's root namespace (i.e. turning the path into an absolute path).

```
pub mod a {
    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        println!("{:?}", ::std::fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
    }
}
```

The recommended practice is to import types (structs, enums, etc.) directly (e.g. `use std::rc::Rc;`, then use the path `Rc`), but to use functions through an import of their parent module (e.g. `use std::io::fs;`, then use the path `fs::remove_file`).

```
pub mod a {
    use std::fs;

    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        println!("{:?}", fs::remove_file("Somefilehere"));
    }
}
```

*Side note:* You can also write `self::` at the beginning of a path to make it relative to the current module. This is more often used in `use` statements, since other paths are already relative (though they are relative to the current *namespace*, whereas `self::` is always relative to the containing *module*).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Is it considered better practice to use the path beforehand instead of going through the paths (std::io::some::other::path)?

Comment: I'm a Rust newbie also, so I'm still not clear on what are the best practices. I would say go with the level of specificity that you feel most comfortable with - You can also just `use std::io::fs`, and then call as `fs::unlink`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, `std` is directly accessible from everywhere, so the code you showed is compiling as you would expect.

Furthermore, `extern crate` is no longer needed in Rust edition 2018. Adding a dependency to `Cargo.toml` makes the crate name directly available as a top-level identifier.